# recentf-mode, for files opened with sudo

Tags: recentf

Is this recentf-mode supposed to work for files opened with sudo? I only find files that are opened normally in the list.

I open files with sudo like C-x C-f /sudo://

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should. Make sure you don't have "sudo" in the variable `recentf-exclude` (`C-h v recentf-exclude`).

Comment: Hmm, it seems they are read only when I reopen them from this list?

Comment: they always open read only, when I pick them from this list. Any ideas? This is not happening with you?

Comment: i explicitly exclude "tramp-ish" file paths from `recentf`